# About using IUP.Text:action in Lua

Tags: lua, iup

friends.

In the attached file, I show an example of a form in Lua language using the IUP gui.

The needing is that with every key pressed in the first textbox some calculations be made and the result must be shown in the second textbox.

The problem that I found is that it the answer is showed lately... this means...

A digit is pressed... but the result is not shown.

A second digit is pressed.... the result that is shown is as if in first textbox was only the first digit.

A third digit is pressed.... the result that is shown is as if in first textbox were the first two digits.

And so on.

Can You say me where is my inconsistency with the code?

My goal is to develop the seven GUIs proposed in 7GUIs:
https://github.com/eugenkiss/7guis

But I need to resolve some points as this.

Thanks, friends.

**HERNAN**.

```
---------------------------------
-- Temperatura.lua
-- Hernán Cano Martínez
-- Ene-2018
---------------------------------

package.cpath = "?.dll;?53.dll;lua533/?.dll;lua533/?53.dll;"   -- [in Windows]

require ( "iuplua" )

-- iup.key_open()  -- is obsolete and not necessary anymore in since IUP 3.0 RC 3 .

-- ***************************************************************************

-- los controles que usaremos en nuestro formulario

txtC = iup.text   { value="0"          , expand='NO', floating='NO', rastersize = "70"   , cx="030", cy= "30", font ="Courier New, 10", NC='10', ACTIVE='YES', ALIGNMENT='ACENTER' }
lblC = iup.label  { title = "Celsius =", expand='NO', floating='NO', rastersize = "85x25", cx="110", cy= "27", font ="Courier New, 10" }  -- size  in pixels

txtF = iup.text   { value="0"          , expand='NO', floating='NO', rastersize = "70"   , cx="200", cy= "30", font ="Courier New, 10", NC='10', ACTIVE='YES', ALIGNMENT='ACENTER' }
lblF = iup.label  { title = "Farenheit", expand='NO', floating='NO', rastersize = "85x25", cx="280", cy= "27", font ="Courier New, 10" }  -- size  in pixels

btnC = iup.button { title = "Cerrar"   , expand='NO', floating='NO', rastersize = "75x25", cx="200", cy="100", font ="Segoe IU, 9", TIP='Haga click para cerrar' }

-- ***************************************************************************

-- el Contenedor de controles

vArea = iup.cbox{ expand='NO', floating='NO', size = "450x200",
  txtC, lblC, txtF, lblF, --btnC,
  nil
}

-- El formulario

frmTemperatura = iup.dialog{ expand='NO', floating='NO', 
  vArea,
  title = "Temperatura", 
  size = "300x100"
}

-- ********************************** Callbacks *****************************************

function btnC:action()
  -- Exits the main loop
  return iup.CLOSE  
end


function txtC:action(t)

   if txtC.value and tonumber(txtC.value) then
      local nNum = 0 
      nNum = tonumber(txtC.value)
      txtF.value = nNum * (9/5) + 32
   end
   -- return iup.CONTINUE  -- HCM: I am not sure         
end

function txtF:action(t)

   if txtF.value and tonumber(txtF.value) then
      local nNum = 0 
      nNum = tonumber(txtF.value)
      txtC.value = nNum * (9/5) + 32
   end
   -- return iup.CONTINUE  -- HCM: I am not sure         
end

--------------------------------------------

-- Ahora sí: mostremos el formulario

frmTemperatura:showxy(iup.CENTER,iup.CENTER)

-- to be able to run this script inside another context
-- if (iup.MainLoopLevel()==0) then
if (not iup.MainLoopLevel or iup.MainLoopLevel()==0) then
  iup.MainLoop()
end

----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

The action callback is called during value modification, so if you consult the attribute during the callback it will return the old value. The new value is passed as a parameter in the callback. So you should change your code to:

```
function txtC:action(c, new_value)
   if new_value and tonumber(new_value) then
      local nNum = tonumber(new_value)
      txtF.value = nNum * (9/5) + 32
   end
end

function txtF:action(c, new_value)
   if new_value and tonumber(new_value) then
      local nNum = tonumber(new_value)
      txtC.value = nNum * (9/5) + 32
   end
end
```

Comment: Yes, Antonio. It runs. Thanks for your help. I beg our pardon, because I do not read enough the IUP Help: it is there. Next time I read it before ask. See you later.